# easiest way to substract in one column and add in other

Tags: sql, addition, denormalized

Basically I'm trying to move existances from one register to another, substracting from the origin point and adding it to the destiny. I have one table of "Stocks" like this:

**country city value**

```
AA      01   500
AA      02   400
BB      01   300
CC      01   100
CC      02  1000
CC      03  2000
```

And I am receiving a document of "movements" with a structure like this:
**quantity originCountry originCity endCountry endCity**

```
10      AA             01         CC         01
20      AA             01         BB         02
50      BB             01         CC         03
```

Is there a way to do this without creating two normalized tables and several queries.

***Edit***

The answer must be like this:

**quantity originCountry originCity endCountry endCity**

```
AA      01   470
AA      02   400
BB      01   250
CC      01   110
CC      02  1020
CC      03  2050
```

negative number and business rules aren't relevant

Comment: Edit your question and specify what the result should be.

Comment: if i understand what you are asking, this will become 2 update statements.  one to subtract the value from the origin row, and another to add the value tot he destination row.  you will need to account for the possibilities that either of those rows does not exist or that you go below 0 or any other business rules as well..

Comment: I updated the question adding the expected answer

Comment: Creating two updates is the best way to do it? Don't worry about bussiness rules I control the min and max quantities of existances and movements in another point

Answer (score 0):

try this (isnull is for tsql):

```
SELECT country, city, value - isnull(p, 0) + isnull(m, 0) as q
FROM Stocks AS s
LEFT JOIN (SELECT originCountry, originCity, Sum(quantity) m FROM movements GROUP BY originCountry, originCity) AS mm 
  ON originCountry = s.country AND originCity = s.city
LEFT JOIN (SELECT endCountry, endCity, Sum(quantity) p FROM movements GROUP BY endCountry, endCity) AS mp ON
  ON endCountry = s.country AND endCity = s.city
```

For **MS ACCESS** (add tag next time...):
this should by work:

```
SELECT country, city, value - Nz(p, 0) + Nz(m, 0) as q
FROM ((Stocks AS s
LEFT JOIN (SELECT originCountry, originCity, Sum(quantity) m FROM movements GROUP BY originCountry, originCity) AS mm 
  ON (originCountry = s.country AND originCity = s.city))
LEFT JOIN (SELECT endCountry, endCity, Sum(quantity) p FROM movements GROUP BY endCountry, endCity) AS mp ON
  ON (endCountry = s.country AND endCity = s.city))
```

or this ((if you get error then use DSum function):

```
SELECT country, city, value 
  - Nz((
    SELECT Sum(quantity) m 
    FROM movements 
    WHERE originCountry = s.country AND originCity = s.city
  ), 0) + Nz((
    SELECT Sum(quantity) p 
    FROM movements 
    WHERE endCountry = s.country AND endCity = s.city
  ), 0) as q
FROM Stocks AS s
```

Comment: for mysql use `ifnull`, for oracle `nvl`

Comment: sorry for being so noob I'm getting a error in the join, How I must related the tables? country with originCountry and endCountry, city with origin city and endCity?

Comment: 1 What dbms you use? 2 What error you get? Relations are defined in `ON` conditions.

Comment: I am using MS access 2010 (supports ISNULL()) and I am getting a "join expression not supported". I Also removed the duplicated On in the second join but still no luck. I am going now for the double update as suggested by Randy